# Send image from one activity to another activity imageview

Tags: android

In the first activity the camera is open in the surfaceview and on click on the capture button when the image is clicked its preview is shown on the next activity of the imageview.Plz help me

My First Activity:

public class CodeActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

```
Button btn;
ImageView imgss;
public static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
String selectedImagePath;
Context context;
Bitmap image;
Bundle bundle;
Intent intent;
String pictureFile;
String fileName;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean previewing = false;
//public static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private Camera mCamera;
//private CameraPreview mPreview;
private PictureCallback mPicture;
private Button capture, switchCamera;
private Context myContext;
//private LinearLayout cameraPreview;
private boolean cameraFront = false;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_code);
    myContext = this;
    context = this;

     //getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);


    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    imgss = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              /* Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);*/

            mCamera.takePicture(null, null,  myPictureCallback_JPG);


        }
    });

    imgss.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        //sendImage();  
        }
    });




}


/*PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Bitmap bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);
        File imageDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "surbeyImg");
        imageDirectory.mkdirs();
        File imgName = null;
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
         + File.separator + "surbeyImg" + File.separator + imgName+".jpg");
         try 
         {
                f.createNewFile();
                //write the bytes in file
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                fo.write(data);
          } catch (IOException e) 
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        Intent intentImg = new Intent(CodeActivity.this, PassActivity.class);
         intentImg.putExtra("img",imgName);
         startActivity(intentImg); 

    }
};*/


/*PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        String fileName = "tempIMG.png";
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutStream = openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
            fileOutStream.write(data);
            fileOutStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent i = new Intent(context, PassActivity.class);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putByteArray("photo", fileName);
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

};*/

```
PictureCallback  myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback() {
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, PassActivity.class);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putByteArray("photo", data);
    i.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

};

My Next Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pass);


    /*imgss = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagereceieve);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String photoPath = extras.getString("photoPath");
    File filePath = getFileStreamPath(photoPath);

    imgss.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath));*/


    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    byte[] photo = extras.getByteArray("photo");


    Bitmap bitmap  = decodeByteArray (photo, 0, photo.length);
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagereceieve);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: did you tried something or at least Google'd ?

Comment: I have done a code for it...the image captured is directly pass to another activity...in my code in next activity it will show nothing

Comment: please post your code and ask what you want to ddo with it.

Comment: my first activity...in which image clicked and pass to another activity

Comment: In next activity the image is not showing in image view..plz check my code and tell me...where i am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should initialize the byte array first. so before assign,  change your code like this

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] photo = new byte [2048];
photo = extras.getByteArray("photo");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photo , 0, photo .length);
imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Inside button click add this code

```
Intent i = new Intent(current_activity.this, Next_Activity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putByteArray("photo", photo); // photo is an byte array you already stored data in it
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

Receive image on your next activity like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.next_activty);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] photo = new byte [2048];
photo = extras.getByteArray("photo");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photo , 0, photo .length);
imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);   
}
```

Comment: And how to set in image view....by using this code : Bitmap bitmap  = decodeByteArray (photo, 0, photo.length); It will return null

Comment: just edited my post. just do that

Comment: I have one more question...can u solve my problem

Comment: you are welcome. then don't forget to mark it as an answer. yes please ask.

Comment: how to pass this image in imageview to next activity...plz help me

Comment: that's what you did that know. or you can create a image file from this byte stream and then pass the created file path to whatever activity you needed or you can do the same by passing byte array to next activity like you did.

Comment: I want to pass this image to next activity on button click...i want that code

Comment: bundle.putByteArray("photo", data); : this line gives the error store the data into variable.  Create local variable of data

Comment: now also giving error of: change the modifier of photo to final

Comment: then make the photo variable as final. are you using eclipse or android studio?

Comment: I am using eclipse...i do that variable final but after that : final byte[] photo = new byte [2048];
then this line gives error remove final :photo = extras.getByteArray("photo");

Comment: put cursor on error and press ctrl+space button.. eclipse will suggest you how to clear the current error.

Comment: If I change then it will give cannot refer non final photo variable inside an inner class defined in different class

Comment: It will give null pointer exception at: Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photo , 0, photo .length); on next activity